# How to connect to microsoftTeams with powershell and Orchestrator 2016?

Tags: powershell, orchestration, runbook

I'm having a hard time connecting to Microsoft Teams with Microsoft Orchestrator 2016. When I run my powershell code with RunbookTester, the code ends successfully. However, when I use another platform to test the same runbook, there is always a problem with the connection. I've checked and the module is well instled and imported. Here is my code:

```
  $User = "xxx@contoso.com"
  $PassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "YourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
  $UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $PassWord

  Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $UserCredential
```

The errors occurs in the last command, with the credentials, which is strange because this does not happen when I run the runbook with runbookTester.
I've done some research and found this command:

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

I'm not sure what this command does and if it will solve my problem. Has someone has the same problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Please include this in your post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it«s mostly SocketException, HttpRequestException, WebException and AggregateException